# Is it possible to batch adding polygons to GoogleMap View (APIv2)

Tags: android, google-maps, drag-and-drop, touch, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm drawing a bunch (50-500) polygons on a Google MapView (API v2) in Android 4.0+, and trying to modify them with a touch event. The touch event I trap via dispatchTouchEvent(), and it's working, just very slowly. The performance is bad enough that it doesn't 'feel' like it's working.

I believe the problem lies in the fact that I have to loop through a collection of polygons, adding them to the map one at a time, so the map redraws with each one.

Looking through the documentation I cant see a way to add multiple polygons at once, but maybe I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

My dispatchTouchEvent looks something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(mInDrag||mInRotate||mInAB){
        if (ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            mStartPt = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(new Point((int)ev.getX(), (int)ev.getY()));
            mLastDragTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if (ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){                
            LatLng endPt = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(new Point((int)ev.getX(), (int)ev.getY()));
            long iterationTime = System.currentTimeMillis()-mLastDragTime;
            //checking iterationtime so grid doesn't move after the user stops dragging
            if ((!mStartPt.equals(endPt))&&iterationTime<300) {
                LatLng delta = new LatLng(mStartPt.latitude-endPt.latitude, mStartPt.longitude-endPt.longitude);
                mLastDragTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (mInDrag) {
                    //setup calcs
                } else if (mInAB){
                    //setup calcs
                } else if (mInRotate){
                    //setup calcs
                }
                clearTempGrid(); //clears the grid including erasing the existing polygons on the map.
                int gridType = gridTypeSpin.getSelectedItemPosition();
                for (PolygonOptions newPolygon : myPolygonGrid.modify(A, B)) {
                    //I run into problems here. Even 150 polygons slows it down
                    Polygon myPolygon = mMap.addPolygon(newPolygon);
                    tempPolygons.add(myPolygon);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure what you want is to modify all Polygons when dragging?

Add Polygons once and not clear and recreate them every time you get touch event.

Modify them (all?) with `Polygon.setPoints(...)`.

Comment: Modifying the polygons is a great idea that I didn't think of. The reason that won't work is that the arraylist of polygons to draw may change size from iteration to iteration. If nothing else shows up I may try and fix the number of polygons and try the modify method. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Nothing stops you from adding Polygons to and removing from the list as needed. The logic will be a bit more complex.